# Confusion in proof of Hall's theorem from Diestel

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Diestel has given a nice third proof of Hall's theorem in graph theory in his seminal book.

I came across the following inequality and can not make sense as to why is it correct?

$\left|N_{H}\left(A_{1} \cap A_{2} \backslash\{a\}\right)\right| \leqslant\left|B_{1} \cap B_{2}\right|$

This appears on Page 39 of Section 2.1 in his fifth edition.

[image]

Comment: If $x\in A_1\cap A_2$, then all its neighbors are both in $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Comment: So it must be an equality sign right? My only confusion is that I get why equality occurs similar to what you said, but why ever will the inequality sceanrio arise?

Comment: @Berci I think it is due to the property of the element `a`